# Ordering thumbs up results by vote count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Still a rails newbie, trying to order the following list by the sum of `votes_for+votes_against` on subitems, with thumbs_up the votes live in another table though

```
@subitems = @items.subitems
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
@items = Item.plusminus_tally({:order => "vote_count ASC"})
```

I included the order override in there, in case you wanted to change it from the default of descending order. This is for Rails 3.

A subitem should have it's own:

```
acts_as_voteable
```

in its model.